# SX126x Get RX payload size

Tags: stm32, lora, lorawan, modulation

I am using the **SX1262** for receiving packets with **EXPLICIT_HEADER_MODE** enabled (the header is present). I have the latest libraries from Semtech ([link](https://github.com/Lora-net/SWL2001/blob/master/smtc_modem_core/radio_drivers/sx126x_driver/src/sx126x.c)). The problem is that when I receive data, the `sx126x_get_rx_buffer_status` function is called to determine the size of the received packet. However, this function returns incorrect information about the payload length. Although when I read the data buffer, the data is received correctly.